# Guardar Byte() vb.net en Image SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net

Quisiera guardar esta variable

```
ByVal imageSelected As Byte()
```

En un cambo en mi Base de datos de tipo Image

En que formato tendria que cambiarlo, o como seria la funcion para guardarlo ? Gracias.

Les dejo mi funcion de guardar imagen, no me estaria insertando la imagen.

```
    Public Sub AgregarUnDato(ByVal acct As Integer, ByVal imageSelected As Byte(), ByVal typeImg As String, Optional ByVal Trans As SqlClient.SqlTransaction = Nothing)
    Try
        Dim st As New Stopwatch
        st.Start()
        Dim MyConn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
        If Trans Is Nothing Then
            MyConn = conexion
        Else
            MyConn = Trans.Connection
        End If
        Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("UPDATE IMAGENES Set @typeImg = @imagen WHERE ((JugId = @jugId))", MyConn)
        If Not Trans Is Nothing Then
            cmd.Transaction = Trans
        End If

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jugId", acct)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@typeImg", typeImg)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imagen", imageSelected)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If Trans Is Nothing Then
            MyConn.Close()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto debe funcionar

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=myserver;Initial Catalog=MiBaseDeDatos;Integrated Security=True")
con.Open()
Dim sql As String = "Insert into test1 (imagen) Values(@miImagen)"
Dim param As New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@miImagen", SqlDbType.Image)
param.Value = imageSelected 
Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, con)
cmd.Parameters.Add(param)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
```

Comment: Gracias por responder! Agrege el parametro Sqldbtype.Image (Edite mi pregunta con mas codigo) pero me devuelve este error: {"Conflicto de tipos de operandos: image es incompatible con nvarchar"}

Comment: Qué tipo de datos tiene el campo de la imagen en SQL?

Comment: Esto está mal: `UPDATE IMAGENES Set @typeImg = @imagen` . @typeImg debe ser el nombre del campo de SQL a actualizar

Comment: typeImg porque la tabla tiene varias columnas de imagenes, le paso en cual quiero modificar la imagen. El campo de datos es Image en la tabla SQL

Comment: Roger, gracias, el error estaba en que tenia que concatenar el @typeImg. Ya me funciona modificando eso y agregando tu respuesta!